# Vanishing gradient of a surface $z=f(x,y)$ by a rigid motion

Tags: differential-geometry, rigid-transformation

I'm reading the wikipedia pages on some differential geometry topics, e.g. Gaussian curvature. Let's draw our attention to surfaces $z=f(x,y)$ in 3D Euclidian space.

The text states the following:

*We represent the surface as the graph of a function, f, of two variables, in such a way that the point $\vec{p}$ is a critical point, i.e., the gradient of f vanishes (this can always be attained by a suitable rigid motion).*

Then the Gaussian curvature of the surface at $\vec{p}$ is the determinant of the Hessian matrix of $f(x,y)$.

I was wondering how you can get $\bigtriangledown f(\vec{p})=0$ by a rigid motion. Can anyone give an example?

I can't even imagine the truth of this statement in 2D ($f'(x_0)=0$ after a suitable transformation of the $x$ and $y$-axes.). An example here is welcome too!

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The gradient is preserved by rigid motions, so this doesn't seem to make sense. Would you mind linking to the wikipedia page?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature, "further informal discussion".

Comment: I think the text is just saying that you can rotate the surface so that the tangent plane is horizontal (if it isn't already).

Comment: I understand. I confused $\bigtriangledown f=(f_x,f_y)$ with the normal vector $(f_x,f_y,-1)$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can always represent a regular surface $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the zero set of some function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla F$ is nowhere zero on $\Sigma$. (Take, e.g., the square of the distance function from $\Sigma$.)

Choose a point $p\in\Sigma$. By a rigid motion we may arrange so that $p=0$ and $\nabla F_p$ is vertical. Now by the implicit function theorem, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p(=0)$ and function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that in $U$, 
$$ F(x,y,f(x,y)) = 0. $$

That is, in $U$, the surface $\Sigma\cap U$ coincides with the graph of $f$.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting comment. I was wondering if you could give me a reference to the proof of "such that ∇F is nowhere zero on Σ". Your example "e.g., the square of the distance function from Σ" is nice, but I don't understand it completely. What distance is calculated, from which point to which point?

Comment: @StevenVanGeluwe For $p$, take the inf over $q\in\Sigma$ of $d(p,q)$. If $\Sigma$ is closed, then for $p\notin\Sigma$ there is a $q$ where this is realized and not zero, and if $p$ is close enough to $\Sigma$ this $q$ is unique.